# @RequestParam consumes Both GET and POST Params

Tags: java, spring, rest, post, get

This probably comes down to bad design and Implementation. But we're upgrading our Jersey to Spring based Servlets for our REST API's.

Now we've noticed that request which use both GET and POST (don't ask me why some people implemented it that way). Get Consumed as Array, or at least comma separated;

F/E if a Requests has a form param amount=5 and in the url ?amount=5. The @RequestParam String amount variable consumes the request as "5,5".

Is this intended behaviour? are there workaround like giving one of the options precedence?

Comment: Why do you POST something with query String in URL?

Comment: As I said, I don't know but people have implemented our API that way, always posting and putting things in the Query params. I think it's a silly thing todo but I also can't fix their projects.

Right now we're temporarily setting params to be arrays and use the first. It's stupid but works until we fixed the front-ends.

Comment: To be short, some front ends have been set up with a group of php developers who arent too bright. So they implemented only 1 option as params, and some methods require a few posts and 1 get param (Token in get f/e).

They just post all and querystring all since that worked with Jersey.

Comment: I think our only option is to force the front ends to be fixed.

Comment: Yeah, I do think so, too. Good Luck!

Comment: Yes we're hacking around those front-ends. Thanks